# Laravel 5.2 : Fresh Install Authentication (Registration) not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

In `Laravel 5.2` fresh installation, i'm trying to get the Authentication features **(Register/ Login/ Logout/ etc)**, by following the documentations. Here are the steps i made.

# php artisan make:auth

```
Created View: /var/www/html/example.com/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/html/example.com/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/html/example.com/resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/html/example.com/resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/html/example.com/resources/views/auth/emails/password.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/html/example.com/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/html/example.com/resources/views/home.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/html/example.com/resources/views/welcome.blade.php
Installed HomeController.
Updated Routes File.
Authentication scaffolding generated successfully!
```

# cat app/Http/routes.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

# php artisan migrate:install

```
Migration table created successfully.
```

# php artisan migrate

```
Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
```

*(Here i'm not sure why it is dated as "2014", anyway.)*

After this, i can already see below tables get created in my MySQL database:

- migrations
- password_resets
- users

[ So i assume the **Database connection is also correct**! ]
[ And also the Home page with "Login" "Register" "Login Form" etc are appeared, properly. ]

### Problem

Now, when i go to `/register` there's a nice Registration Form already appeared. But when i fill-in and SUBMIT, nothing happens. (It keeps routed back to the `/register` page as nothing happened.)

Then when i checked from Apache Access Logs, the request is shown as "GET". I think this is supposed to be a "POST". Am i right?

(And nothing in the Error Logs as well)

What is happening please?

Comment: What is your controller file for register?

Comment: This is my first Laravel installation. So I'm not sure. But according to tutorials, after these steps, the login/logout/registrations should be already working. Am i right to say that please? (Because this is purposely the feature of LV5.2. Right?)

Comment: AuthController needed for laravel authentication.You can try step by step from https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate.It is very easy for a beginner.

Comment: move your all routes to the group and thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it solved by myself.

(1) It needs following functions in the `app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php`:

```
public function getRegister()
{
    return $this->showRegistrationForm();
}

public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    return $this->register($request);
}
```

(2) In the Router `routes.php` file, the function `Route::auth();` call must be defined only *after* the other functions (under the same middleware group). Like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {    
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::auth();
});
```

( The `Route::auth();` can not come first. )

Thanks all for all your kind helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `web` middleware, cause a lot of guys have issues with it past two weeks (since minor Laravel update). Now `web` middleware applies automatically to all routes and when you add it manually, it causes different kind of errors.

Comment: Which `web` middleware you mean please? Because i used 2 of them in my file above. Or you mean to totally remove all `web` middlewares at all? (By the way, i found there's no `function register` in my `AuthController.php`. Is it normal? Is it inherited from somewhere?)

Comment: Remove all `web` from routes. AuthController uses two traits, so I guess function is in one of them.